# How to debug simple promises in node.js properly?

Tags: node.js, debugging, promise, visual-studio-debugging

My problem is that when I'm debugging my node app, I can't see the results of the promises by simply running debug.

For instance, I have the following code that I can't debug:

```
sampleRepository
    .find()
        .then(result => result)  // breakpoint goes here
        .catch(err => err)
```

When I put the breakpoint there, I can't see the value of the result variable. So I'm having to refactor the code to work around it.
What I'm doing as a work around is:

```
sampleRepository
        .find()
            .then(result => {
                return result; // breakpoint goes here
            })  
            .catch(err => err)
```

It works, because now I can see the value of the "result" variable, but I have to refactor the code everytime. Is there a simpler way to debug those promises instead refactoring the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `vscode` does already support this. You set the breakpoint on your `then`-handler and then use **step into** once the breakpoint is hit. Check this little .gif I made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C44An.jpg

Note: I'm using version **1.45.1**